# Safari crashes ~10% of times when opening a link (any link)

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I use 9.1. This happens when I have disabled extensions too, is there anything else I can try, and/or is this a known problem, if so, is there any solution.

I might have to delete the preferences, but I want to try other things if it works.

Comment: Does console.app show anything? Can you add the crash reports from Safari?

Comment: Have you tried deleting ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState before going as far as clearing everything. Also test on Guest or another admin account.